# Removing row not reflected in datatable after update

Tags: ajax, primefaces, jsf-2, datatable

My delete button will delete an entry from the database but not from the actual datatable in primefaces. Until you refresh it with either a filter change or F5/new session.

I've looked at various other answers to this question and am coming up blank. I've tried messing with the update and using oncomplete="PF('datalistWidget').filter()" among other things.

Using primefaces 6.0 and glassfish 4.1. Any help appreciated. 
I roughly followed the tutorial at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java-primefaces-2191907.html and then added on my own customization. The managed beans and facade etc... are all similar to that tutorial with the database created classes. I have not seen any errors in the glassfish log.

**DataTable**

```
<p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{chemicalChemicalController.items}" var="item"
         selectionMode="single" selection="#{chemicalChemicalController.selected}"
         paginator="true"
         editable ="true"
         rowKey="#{item.chemKey}"
         rows="10" 
         widgetVar="datalistWidget"
         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50"
         filteredValue="#{chemicalChemicalController.itemsFiltered}"
         >
```

**Delete Command Button**

```
<p:commandButton id="deleteButton" icon="ui-icon-trash"
value="#{bundle.Delete}" actionListener="#{chemicalChemicalController.destroy}" 
update=":growl, datalist" disabled="#{empty chemicalChemicalController.selected}"/>
```

**Controller Delete Command**

```
   public void destroy() {
    persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ChemicalChemicalDeleted"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        selected = null; // Remove selection
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.

    }
}
```

Comment: Like the answer states, you nowhere seem to either remove the item from the list or indicate you fullybreload the list from the db

Answer (score 0):

destroy method with deleting from items object.

```
public void destroy(SelectEvent event) {
    persist(PersistAction.DELETE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("ChemicalChemicalDeleted"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        selected = null; // Remove selection
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.

    }

    RowObj rowObj = (RowObj) event.getObject();// here Row Object is your selected row item.
   if(items != null)
   {
      //iterate items and delete matched with selected row object 
   }
}
```